# How to turn this into a straight line

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, data-analysis

Right now, I am trying to turn my graph (which looks like a exponential graph) into a straight line graph, which starts at the origin (0,0). How would I do this? My values are given in the attachment, and I have uploaded a picture of my graph (what the exponential graph looks like).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhEDL.jpg - Values

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mB61m.jpg - Graph

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought your graph should be plotted with the axes the other way round, because the length of skid mark is the dependent variable.

If you do this you should have some kind of parabola (in theory!), which if you take thinking/reaction time ($T$) into account will have a form something like $$S=vT+kv^2$$ where $k$ is some constant.
I don't think you can make a straight line of this that goes through the origin, but you can make a straight line by plotting $S/v$ against $v$:
$$S/v = T+kv$$
which will have y-intercept $T$ and gradient $k$.

If you are not taking reaction time into account, then you can use $S=kv^2$, and then you could plot $S$ against $v^2$, or $S/v$ against $v$ to get $k$ as the gradient (or plot $\ln S$ against $\ln v$ but this might be overkill).

Comment: But im not using time, so what would i do?

Comment: In either case, $S/v$ (y) against $v$ (x) will give you a straight line.

Comment: 1.) It's not clear that reaction time need be considered at all.  It appears to me that he knows the speed at the start of the skid, and then simply measures the length of the skid mark.  2.) It's probably valid to add the point (0,0). 3.) Yes, swap the axes.  4.) Yes, plot $S$ *vs* $v^2$

Comment: So either plot $S$ against $v^2$ or $S/v$ against $v$. I would prefer the latter because you can then read the constant directly from the gradient.

Comment: Actually you could do either!